# mysql get non existing results

Tags: php, mysql

Using php and mysql,
I have a table "subdomains" that contains subdomains for my application, depending of a category.
subdomains - id, cat_id, subdomain

Some categories have subdomain and others don't have.
For those that don't have subdomain, I want the subdomain to be 'www'.

Now in my subdomains table there are a few values, for example :

```
subdomains : id, cat_id, subdomain
             1,  6,   "sales"
             2,  7,   "infos"
```

Now, I have an array of cat_id, for example $aCatIds = array(1,5,6,8);

At the end of the mysql query I would like a something like this :

```
array(
0 => (cat_id="1", subdomain="www") ,
1 => (cat_id="5", subdomain="www") ,
2 => (cat_id="6", subdomain="sales") ,
3 => (cat_id="8", subdomain="www") ,
)
```

Is it possible with only one mysql query ?

I use php and tried things like this :

```
$stmt = "select cat_id, ifnull('www', subdomain) as subdomain
    from subdomains
    where cat_id in (". implode(',', $aCatIds) .")";
```

But I only get the values that are set (6 in the above example), and I don't know how to tell mysql to get the expected array.

Comment: What does "don't have subdomain" mean in terms of the actual data in the row?

Comment: if the category has a special subdomain associated to it, it is written in the database, otherwise, it is not written (it doesn't exist in the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, you'll have to (left) join to existing data (where the cat_id does exist). For instance, if I assume a `cat` table exists which the `cat_id` references, 't would be so:

```
SELECT c.id as cat_id,IFNULL(s.subdomain,'www')
FROM cat c 
LEFT JOIN subdomains s
ON s.cat_id = c.id
WHERE c.id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: I tried 
SELECT c.id as cat_id,IFNULL(s.subdomain,'www')
FROM cat c 
LEFT JOIN subdomains s
ON s.cat_id = c.id
WHERE c.id IN (1,5,6,8);


But I get just the "cat_id=6" row.

Comment: Then 1,5 & 8 are also not in the `cat` table, in which table DO they exist? Do they exist in any table at all?

Comment: 1,5,6 and 8 are all in the cat table.
Both cat and subdomains table are of type innoDB.
But 1,5 and 8 are not in the result set, I just get 1 single line,
with the cat_id=6 and subdomain='sales'

Comment: Did you actually use the **LEFT** part of the join? 'Cause if they are in the cat table, this _should_ work.

Comment: YES!
Man, your guess was right!
Me, tired geek, late at night yesterday when transposing your suggestion made a mistake and came up with something like :

SELECT s.cat_id as cat_id,IFNULL(s.subdomain,'www')  
FROM cat c   
LEFT JOIN subdomains s  
ON s.cat_id = c.id  
WHERE s.cat_id IN (1,2,3,4);  

And of course it doesn't work, but this one that you wrote worked :

SELECT c.id as cat_id,IFNULL(s.subdomain,'www')  
FROM cat c   
LEFT JOIN subdomains s  
ON s.cat_id = c.id  
WHERE c.id IN (1,2,3,4);  

I get better understanding of mysql query now.

Thanx a lot ;)